# Console errors when executing shortcode code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am writing the following code in the wordpress shortcode:

```js
$(function () {

    function setFlatTheme() {
        $("body").toggleClass("flat-theme");
        $("#rad-color-opts").toggleClass("hide");
        $(".rad-chk-pin input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
    }

    setFlatTheme();

    $(window).on("scroll", function (e) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $("body").addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $item = $(".rad-dropmenu-item");
        if ($item.hasClass("active")) {
            $item.removeClass("active");
        }
    });

    $(".rad-sidebar a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(".rad-chat-body").slimScroll({
        height: "450px",
        color: "#c6c6c6"
    });

    $(".rad-timeline-body").slimScroll({
        height: "450px",
        color: "#c6c6c6"
    });

    $(".rad-activity-body").slimScroll({
        height: "250px",
        color: "#c6c6c6"
    });

    $(".rad-toggle-btn").on("click", function () {
        $(".rad-logo-container").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
        $(".rad-sidebar").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
        $(".rad-body-wrapper").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
    });

    $("li.rad-dropdown > a.rad-menu-item").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".rad-dropmenu-item").removeClass("active");
        $(this).next(".rad-dropmenu-item").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(".fa-chevron-down").on("click", function () {
        var $ele = $(this).parents(".panel-heading");
        $ele.siblings(".panel-footer").toggleClass("rad-collapse");
    });

    $(".fa-close").on("click", function () {
        var $ele = $(this).parents(".panel");
        $ele.addClass("panel-close");
    });

    $(".fa-rotate-right").on("click", function () {
        var $ele = $(this).parents(".panel-heading").siblings(".panel-body");
        $ele.append(
            '<div class="overlay"><div class="overlay-content"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin"></i></div></div>'
        );
    });

    $("#rad-chat-send").on("click", function () {
        var value = $("#rad-chat-txt").val();
        var $ele = $(".rad-chat-body");
        var img =
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-GXmmnYTuWkg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/oK6DEDS7grM/w56-h56/photo.jpg";
        
        if (value) {
            $("#rad-chat-txt").val("");
            $ele.append(getTempl(img, value, "left"));
            
            $ele.slimScroll({
                scrollTo: $ele[0].scrollHeight
            });
        }
    });

    $(".rad-chk-pin input[type=checkbox]").change(function (e) {
        $("body").toggleClass("flat-theme");
        $("#rad-color-opts").toggleClass("hide");
        var selectedTheme = $(".rad-color-swatch input[type=radio]:checked");
        var fillColor = '#C6C6C6';
        var scale = ["#C8EEFF", "#0071A4"];

        if (this.checked) {
            scale = ["#A8ECFF", "#FA71D4"];
            fillColor = colorMap[selectedTheme.val()];
        }
        
        changeMapColors(fillColor, scale);
    });
    

    var colorMap = {
        crimson: "crimson",
        teal: "#1fb5ad",
        orange: "#ff503f",
        purple: "rebeccapurple",
        twitter: "#55acee"
    };

    $(".rad-color-swatch input[type=radio]").change(function (e) {
        if ($(".rad-chk-pin input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
            $("body").removeClass().addClass("flat-theme").addClass(this.value);
            $(".rad-color-swatch label").removeClass("rad-option-selected");
            $(this).parent().addClass("rad-option-selected");
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        }
    });

    $(".rad-notification-item").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.3/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>


<section>
    <header>
        <nav class="rad-navigation">
            <div class="rad-logo-container rad-nav-min">
                <a href="#" class="rad-logo"><img src="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" class="tamimg"><span class="letra">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="rad-toggle-btn pull-right"><i class="fa fa-bars acertobar"></i></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="rad-logo-hidden">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a>
            <div class="rad-top-nav-container">
                <ul class="pull-right links">
                        
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-right links">
                    <li>
                        <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #31547c; font-weight: 600;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</section>
<aside>
    <nav class="rad-sidebar rad-nav-min">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" class="inbox">
                    <i class="fa fa-home acerto"><span class="icon-bg"></span></i>
                    <span class="rad-sidebar-item">HOME</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/teste.php">
                    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o">
                        <span class="icon-bg"></span>
                    </i>
                    <span class="rad-sidebar-item">INSCRIÇÃO</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
<main>

</main>
```

But when I consult the console it returns these errors:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).slimScroll is not a function TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (:33:22)
> at e (https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2:30005)
> at t (https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pt/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2:30307) undefined

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function
> at HTMLDocument.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Can anyone help?

Comment: just read the errors

Comment: @KetZoomer I've read the errors, but I don't see how to fix them. already replaces the libraries with others and I continue with the problem

Comment: @KetZoomer Can it help to understand what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the code is probably running before the page fully loads, try doing

```
window.onload = function() {

}
```

or

```
jQuery.ready(function() {

}
```

Comment: Resolved the first two errors on the console. But the third error still returns: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`. Can you help resolve this error as well?

Comment: I do not see where you are using options, can you send the part of the code using this?

Comment: Here I have the complete code, add the css [link](https://codepen.io/bruno-pinto-the-looper/pen/MWpbajB)

Comment: I still cannot find where "options" is in your javascript

Comment: But here is my complete code, what is causing this error?

Comment: What exactly is options?  Are you sure you don't have any other script?

Comment: I resolved, removing this library `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. I think that was what was causing the error. The page takes the library of the theme and when I put it I was duplicating it. Now I got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: parent.keydown is not a function`

Comment: Just a side note, since you're using wordpress, you should be using wp_enqueue_scripts() to add scripts to your pages.  That way you can also add dependencies like;

wp_enqueue_script('script-name', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/your-plugin', array('jquery'));